# Just another layout issue - layout_gravity

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to implement a layout for a table-row. I have two TextViews which should be alligned to the left and one image that should be alligned to right.

Unfortunately my layout looks like this *(everything is alligned to the left)*:

[image]

I'm fiddling with this for over an hour now and don't get it to work. What do I have to change to get the image alligned to the right?

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />        

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same in **LinearLayout** using **weight** but weight is only used in making complex layouts now to avoid usage of weight, I would suggest you to transform your UI in **RelativeLayout**. In this way, you can save a lot of extra lines of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />        

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or if you dont want to use `RelativeLayout` and want to stick with your `LinearLayout` then try giving weight to the first `LinearLayout` and `layout_gravity="right|end"` to the `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />        

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Try using Relative layout as the root layout. In this case I think it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using a `RelativeLayout`, you can use layout weights to set your second `LinearLayout` to use all the space available :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` on the parent and add the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` attribute to your image